# Deselecting an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a collection of `span` elements. In the code I have a global variable that represents the "selected" object. Using the `click` event when a `span` is clicked I reset the object's class, reset the global variable, then set the object to the variable and change its class (to make it "highlighted"). This effectively toggles selection when clicking an object.

```
var currentItem = null;
$( ".item" ).click( function() {
    if( $( this ).hasClass( "selected" ) ) {
        $( this ).removeClass( "selected" )
        currentItem = null;
    } else {
        if( $( ".item" ).hasClass( "selected" ) ){
            $( ".item" ).removeClass( "selected" )
        }

            $( this ).addClass( "selected" );
            currentItem = $( this );
        }
} );
```

What I'd like to be able to do is unselect when clicking on an empty area of the page. I tried creating a click event on the `body` object, but that overrode the `span` click event so nothing was selected. I'm a complete jQuery noob and not sure where to go with this.

Comment: Quick note on selecting a Best Answer: Nick Craver responded first and his answer was accurate. Gaby posted shortly thereafter and the response was clear, concise, and equally accurate. I'd give either one of these individuals the credit. :)

Comment: Yeah, the only part of SO that I don't like so much: picking the winners when its close like that.

Comment: Quick note on selecting a Best Answer: I have every confidence in your own capacity for judgement and discernment that you can figure out such a simple task for yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) in your current handler so that `click` doesn't bubble up to the `<body>`, triggering it's handler as well, then your approach works, like this:

```
var currentItem = null;
$(".item").click(function(e) {
  if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
    $(this).removeClass("selected")
    currentItem = null;
  } else {
    $(".item.selected").removeClass("selected");
    currentItem = $(this).addClass("selected");
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $(".item.selected").removeClass("selected");
});
```

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NZp8N/), one suggestion though, if only one element can be `selected` do you need to keep track of it?  If lookup cost isn't a factor, you could aways find the `currentItem` by doing `$(".item.selected")`, simplifying this code quite a bit. I'm not sure how you're using `currentItem`, just an option you have :)

Comment: Nick... do you ever sleep? :D

Comment: @Gert G - Every third sunday on odd months, yes :)

Comment: LOL - That's what I thought. Btw... Good answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

You did well setting a click event on the `body`. BUt you must also tell the span click event to stop the propagation of the event..

```
$( ".item" ).click( function(event) {

    event.stopPropagation();
    //your code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your idea to place the click event on the `body` is fine.

You just need to be aware that clicking on any descendants of `body` will cause the click event to bubble up to `body`, and fire that handler.

You need to stop that propagation in your `span` event handler.

```
$( ".item" ).click( function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    ...
```

**jQuery Docs**

`event.stopPropagation()` http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

---

**EDIT:**

Another valid alternative would be to simply return false at the end of the handler.

```
$( ".item" ).click( function() {
    // Your code...
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a global variable since your DOM holds that state info, too.

```
// de-select old selection and select new item
$(".item").click( function(evt) {
  $(".item.selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  evt.stopPropagation();
});

// de-select everything
$("body").click( function() {
  $(".item.selected").removeClass("selected");
});

// your currently selected element can be retrieved by this anytime:
$(".item.selected")[0]
```

Not tracking state twice (in the DOM and in a global variable) spares you two headaches:

- carefully updating the global variable all the time
- bugs that arise of "global" state getting out of sync with "DOM" state

Answer (score 0):

Create a click on the html element `$("html")` and return it as false whenever you do what you need to do. The body could not extend the whole page if you're doing some sizing with CSS with it. Here's an example:

```
$("html").click( function(e) {

    e.stopPropagation()

});
```

***Edit***

Yeah. forgot about `stopPropagation()`. Changed code to read that. Should still use the html element as the listener, however.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers stated (unless I missed this), you needn't attach the click() event to the body when the page loads -- you can simply do it after the item is selected. Not that it hurts since you're stopping propagation, but in my view its more "correct" to only activate/set an event handler for the duration in which it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Too much code, we can do it easier:

```
"use strict";
/*global $*/
$(function () {
  $('html').live('click', function (e) {
    $('.item.selected').removeClass('selected');

    var $t = $(e.target);
    if ($t.hasClass('item')) {
      $t.addClass('selected');
    }
  });
});
```

Using 'html' to bind event is better due body can be not 100% height, for example. And clicking on empty area return not expected result.

We do not need global object, as this script guarantees that we have only one selected span and we can refer to it with:

```
$('.item.selected');
```